# What is an efficient way of evaluating a polynomial when its roots are known?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

Hypothesis: All calculations and polynomials are defined over a finite field of prime order.

Assume we know all roots $r_i$ of a polynomial: $P(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)...(x-r_n)$ and a set of x-coordinates: $\{x_1,,,x_n\}$.We want to evaluate P(x) at every $x_i$.

**Question**: What is the most efficient of computing $P(x_i)$ for every $x_i$?

We know that $P(x_i)=\prod^{n}_{j=1}(x_i-r_j)$ is a navive way of evaluating $P(x)$ at $x_i$.

Comment: When you describe simply plugging each $x_i$ into the expression you have as "naive", does that mean that you have concrete reason to believe a faster method exists? What is that reason?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I mean is there any faster way of doing it?

Comment: There might be a way if there is something special about the roots. Short of that, no.

Comment: @user4564798 That was not Hennings question. Why do you believe that there is a faster method ? There is no obvious reason,

Comment: Well, if $n$ is ***really*** large, and the order of your finite field is, say, $m$, you could precompute the values of $P$ for all elements of the field in $O(nm)$ time, and then for each $x_i$ you get the value of $P(x_i)$ in constant time (assuming arithmetic operations take constant time), giving the overall performance of $O(nm+n)=O(nm)$. Compared to the straightforward $O(n^2)$ algorithm, this makes sense if $m < n$. Is it the case?

Comment: As IvanNeretin pointed out, there are special cases where can easily go faster. For example if $P(x)=x^n-1$ we can do this in $O(n\log n)$ field operations.

Comment: Well, [this query](https://www.google.ru/search?q=multipoint+polynomial+evaluation+finite+fields) gives many papers on an $O(n \log^2 n)$ general-case algorithm. I thought it could be even done in $O(n \log n)$ (in general cases, too)... will re-read some papers made me think so.

Comment: Looked back - it was $O(M(n)\log n)$ with $M(n)$ the multiplication complexity ;)

Comment: I suspect that to properly answer this question, it would be imperative to know how large or small the number of elements in the field is, compared to $n$.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain to give to concrete parameters: the number of x-coordinate is 201 and the degree of the polynomial is 100. Also,  for the finite field: $\mathbb{F}_p$, $p$ is of $40$-bit size.

Comment: @user4564798 Too small to use FFT-based techniques, I think (not talking about $p$ here).